# Closed-form integral of $\int \left(\frac{Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D}{Ex^3 + Fx^2 + Gx + H}\right)^4 dx$

Tags: integration, closed-form

Is there a closed-form/analytical solution to the integral?

$$
\int \left(\frac{Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D}{Ex^3 + Fx^2 + Gx + H}\right)^4 dx
$$

The function does not seem to fit any of the patterns in the list of rational functions in tables of integrals (for [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions)).

Comment: You could expand the numerator, denominator, and use partial fractions

Comment: @TymaGaidash Expand the numerator, but definitely *factor* the denominator!

Comment: What would be the best way to approach this problem given that the constants $A \ldots H$ are not known or given.

Comment: Correction I meant coefficients $A \ldots H$, not constants.

Answer (score 2):

See [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition).

Every rational function $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ can be writtten as

$p(x)+\displaystyle\sum_j\dfrac{f_j(x)}{g_j(x)}$

where $p,g_j,f_j$ are polynomials such that $g_j$ is the power of an irreducible polynomial and $f_j$ has degree less than the irreducible polynomial of which $g_j$ is the power.

Note that over $\mathbb{R}$, the only irreducible polynomials are quadratic or linear.

Furthermore, the closed forms of $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{(ax+b)^n}\;\text{d}x$, of $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{1}{(cx^2+dx+e)^n}\;\text{d}x$, and of $\displaystyle\int \dfrac{ax+b}{(cx^2+dx+e)^n}\;\text{d}x$

are known.

Therefore, the integral of every rational function has a closed-form expression, which you can find by first finding the partial fraction decomposition of the function.